# Microsoft Access using a table as a reference for a field

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, relational-database

I need to link my tables in such a way that when someone enters a ZIP Code into my table, the County and Region fields will auto-populate from a separate table. I thought I could accomplish this with the Lookup functionality but I must've messed up somewhere.

Using the following code for a separate field titled specialty code which updates based on the specialty.

```
Private Sub SpecialtyCode_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Me.SpecialtyCode.Value = DLookup("[HSD_Code]", "Crosswalk_ProviderHSD", 
"[Specialty] = Me.Specialty.Value")
End Sub
```

Comment: Will they entry data from a form? Then it can be done very easily.

Comment: Yeah I have a pop out form in a datasheet view. They'll be clicking on new record and then entering the data. I edited the original question to include the code I'm currently trying for a separate field calling specialty code which should update based on what the specialty is.

Comment: Can you share a sample file so that we can understand what you are missing. Also we can write some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Write code in afterupdate event. Also use single quote before and after `Me.Specialty.Value`

```
Private Sub SpecialtyCode_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   Me.SpecialtyCode.Value = DLookup("[HSD_Code]", "Crosswalk_ProviderHSD", 
    "[Specialty] = '" & Me.Specialty.Value & "'")
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and something still isn't working correctly. When I open the form and select a specialty from the drop down, the specialty code field isn't updating. I've clicked into the cell and even onto the next record to check. What could be the issue?

Comment: Again I suggest you to share a sample file via google drive or dropbox. It would be better to understand the issue.

Comment: I would love to share a file, but the policy at my workplace prevents any information like that being shared out. I can provide you with a better explanation or answer specific questions that might help you assist me, but I can't share files or information.

Comment: Why will you prove your actual data. Just share dummy data. Without file we can not understand your form and table structure. Just create 1 or 2 table as like your main database. create a form. entry 2 or three false data, then share it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Zip Codes come from a list why not put them into a combo box and bring in the other two fields you need as hidden columns.

Then simply set the other values to the hidden columns in the after update event.